# Using a variable in logit units in a regression (interpretation)

Tags: statistics, regression, logistic-regression

Suppose a dependent variable `amath` measures student's ability in math. The range of this variable is -5 to 5 and it is measured in logit units (it classifies the ability of students that took a standardised test using a Rasch model).

If I used `amath` as a dependent variable in a regression with one independent dummy variable for sex, let's say `man`.

And the coefficient I get as a result is -0.229.

My question is ¿How should this coefficient be interpreted? ¿Does the number has an interpretation or only the sign?

I got confused because I do not know how the units of my dependent variable should be treated.

Answer (score 1):

Logit is essential the logarithm of odds, so taking the anti-logarithm of the coefficient of the dummy variable  would give $e^{-0.229} \approx 0.7953$

This is an odds-ratio figure, and is not easy to interpret.  For example, near the centre and extremes of the distribution of $\pm5$ logit scores:

- If a woman with particular characteristics was expected to get a maths mark of $50\%$ (corresponding to odds of $1$ and a logit score of $0$) then a man with similar characteristics would be expected to get a mark of around $44.3\%$ (corresponding to odds of $0.7953$ and a logit score of $-0.229$)
- If a woman with particular characteristics was expected to get a maths mark of $99\%$ (corresponding to odds of $99$ and a logit score of $4.595$) then a man with similar characteristics would be expected to get a mark of around $98.75\%$ (corresponding to odds of $78.7375$ and a logit score of $4.366$)
- If a woman with particular characteristics was expected to get a maths mark of $1\%$ (corresponding to odds of $0.0101$ and a logit score of $-4.595$) then a man with similar characteristics would be expected to get a mark of around $0.8\%$ (corresponding to odds of $0.0803$ and a logit score of $-4.824$)

Comment: Hello Henry. Thanks for the explanation. However, does this hold even if my model is a multiple linear regression model? If I understand correctly, the coefficients I get are not the odds-ratio I would obtain with a logit. Only my dependent variable comes from a logit model, but the model I am running is not a logit.

Answer (score 0):

That would mean that, regarding the student's ability in math `amath` in the scale -5 to 5, men had on average, a score 0.229 points lower than women.

---

Note that to use a regression is OK if you have other variables besides sex. However, if you are studying the relation between only these two variables, you may use the t-Student's test to compare the score between sexes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But points of what? Ability points? Ability logit points? Does that meant that my variable should be a treated as any other continuous variable? And I am using more variables than just sex, it was just for example purposes.Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I thought that maybe, as my dependent variable came from a logistic distribution it could not be treated as a continuous variable, but as something else. For example, standard deviations in the normal distribution.

Comment: The difference is in the ability in math scores (in the scale -5 to 5). I edited the first sentence in my answer.    As far as I understood, we should assume that the dependent variable is continuous because it is a logit transformation of a score that is assumed to be continuous.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thank you very much.